# Javascript Animate not sliding

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I am tweaking a slider in codepen and now the `animate` function doesn't want to actually do the slide motion. It does move each slide but there is no sliding motion. I can't seem to figure out what the problem is.
Here's the codepen https://codepen.io/theMugician/pen/VxKgBY

```
function moveLeft() {
        $('.slider__slider-list').animate({
            left: + slideWidth
        }, 200, function () {
            $('.slider-list__item:last-child').prependTo('.slider__slider-list');
            $('.slider__slider-list').css('left', '');
        });
    };

    function moveRight() {
        $('.slider__slider-list').animate({
            left: - slideWidth
        }, 200, function () {
            $('.slider-list__item:first-child').appendTo('.slider__slider-list');
            $('.slider__slider-list').css('left', '');
        });
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very good at javascript, but theres no where in the code above where you call or invoke either of the functions. Or, I'm guessing if 200 is the code for one button/reference and that is what is moving it try putting the name of the functions in either of those }, 200, function () { after function....

also it looks like your linking to a Class called .animate but in the CodePen Css there is no class called .animate

hope thi helps but probably not a very good answer

Also You've taken out the click function()

```
$('.slider__control--prev').click(function () {
    moveLeft();
});

$('.slider__control--next').click(function () {
    moveRight();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a **Start slide count** var for detect what's the actual slide. And you can perform a loop slider. Please try bellow. After you can adapt this for you want.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

  $('#checkbox').change(function(){
    setInterval(function () {
        moveRight();
    }, 3000);
  });
  
 var slideCount = $('.slider-list__item').length;
  var slideStart = 0;
 var slideWidth = $('.slider-list__item').width();
 var slideHeight = $('.slider-list__item').height();
 var sliderUlWidth = slideCount * slideWidth;
 
 $('.slider__container').css({ width: slideWidth, height: slideHeight });
 
 $('.slider__slider-list').css({ width: sliderUlWidth });
 
    $('.slider-list__item:last-child').prependTo('.slider__slider-list');

    function moveLeft() {
        slideStart--
        if(slideStart<0){
            slideStart = slideCount-1
         }
        $('.slider-list__item').animate({
            left: -(slideStart*slideWidth)
        }, 200, function () {
        
        });
        
    };

    function moveRight() {
       slideStart++

       if(slideStart>=slideCount){
          slideStart = 0
       }
        $('.slider-list__item').animate({
            left:  -(slideStart*slideWidth)
        }, 200, function () {
        });
        
    };

    $('.slider__control--prev').click(function () {
        moveLeft();
    });

    $('.slider__control--next').click(function () {
        moveRight();
    });

});
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600); 

html {
  border-top: 5px solid #fff;
  background: #000;
  color: #000;
}

html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
}

h1 {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.slider {
  position: relative;
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.slider__container {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
}

.slider-list {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 0;
  height: 200px;
  list-style: none;
}

.slider-list__item {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: left;
}

.slider-list__item p {
  margin: 0 50px;
}

.slider-list__item h1 {
  margin: 20px 50px 0;
}

.slider__control--next, .slider__control--prev {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  z-index: 999;
  display: block;
  padding: 4% 3%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 18px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  cursor: pointer;
}

a.control_prev:hover, a.control_next:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

.slider__control--prev {
  left: -80px;
  border-radius: 0 2px 2px 0;
}

.slider__control--next {
  right: -80px;
  border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
}

.slider_option {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 160px;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider">
 <a href="#" class="slider__control--next">></a>
 <a href="#" class="slider__control--prev"><</a>
<div class="slider__container">
  
  <ul class='slider__slider-list'>
    <li class='slider-list__item' style="background: #333;">
      <h1>SLIDE 1</h1>
      <p>Vestibulum eget vestibulum sapien. Quisque in rhoncus mi, vel posuere libero. Proin blandit placerat nibh, sit amet sodales ex egestas vitae. Maecenas ultrices velit sodales ipsum tristique, eu ornare tortor aliquet. Ut ultrices enim dolor, eu scelerisque elit mattis non. Etiam efficitur nec enim vitae aliquam. Praesent congue metus lorem, sed porttitor nisi tempus tristique.</p>
    </li>
    <li class='slider-list__item'>
      <h1>SLIDE 2</h1>
      <p>Vestibulum eget vestibulum sapien. Quisque in rhoncus mi, vel posuere libero. Proin blandit placerat nibh, sit amet sodales ex egestas vitae. Maecenas ultrices velit sodales ipsum tristique, eu ornare tortor aliquet. Ut ultrices enim dolor, eu scelerisque elit mattis non. Etiam efficitur nec enim vitae aliquam. Praesent congue metus lorem, sed porttitor nisi tempus tristique.</p>
    </li>
    <li class='slider-list__item'>
      <h1>SLIDE 3</h1>
      <p>Vestibulum eget vestibulum sapien. Quisque in rhoncus mi, vel posuere libero. Proin blandit placerat nibh, sit amet sodales ex egestas vitae. Maecenas ultrices velit sodales ipsum tristique, eu ornare tortor aliquet. Ut ultrices enim dolor, eu scelerisque elit mattis non. Etiam efficitur nec enim vitae aliquam. Praesent congue metus lorem, sed porttitor nisi tempus tristique.</p>
    </li>
  </ul>  
</div>
</div>
<div class="slider_option">
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox">
  <label for="checkbox">Autoplay Slider</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It was a simple problem. I forgot to put in the proper class name in the CSS. I had `.slider-list` but it was supposed to be `.slider__slider-list`.
So this had nothing to do with Javascript animations.